# On the size of centralizers in a non-abelian finite simple group

Tags: finite-groups

It is known that for a finite non-abelian simple group $G$ we have $|G|<|C_G(x)|^3$ for some involution $x$. Is there a better bound for the order of centralizer of a nontrivial element of $G$ (not necessarily involution)? For instance, is there always a nontrivial element $x\in G$ such that $|G|<|C_G(x)|^2$?

Comment: Your guess that there would be an $x \in G$ with $|G| < |C_G(x)|^2$ is false already for $G = A_5$.

Comment: It is true in some simple groups and false in others, but generally involutions have the largest centralizers, so allowing other elements is unlikely to affect results of this kind.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the claim is true **provided $|G|$ is large enough**. For alternating groups, take $g$ a $3$-cycle, for groups of Lie type of rank $n$ (most of the time you could) take $g$ central in a Levi subgroup of rank $n-1$. Modulo a load of details I would think that asymptotically you could get $|G|<|C_G(g)|^{1+\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: An aside: Marty Isaacs has proved that **if $G$ is solvable**, then there is a $g$ such that $|G|<|C_G(g)|^2$. The relevant paper is: Isaacs, I. M. *Solvable groups contain large centralizers.*
Israel J. Math. 55 (1986), no. 1, 58–64.

Comment: Finally: regarding my comments about asymptotics above. I think $\varepsilon$ would need to depend on the rank $n$ in the Lie type case, so my guess is not true in general (take $G=PSL_2(q)$ and let $q\to\infty$ for instance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Later edit: Note that in general, the maximal order of the centralizer of a non-identity element in $G_{n} = {\rm SL}(2,2^{n})$ is $2^{n}+1,$ while the group order is $(2^{n}-1)2^{n}(2^{n}+1).$ Hence as $n \to \infty$, the limit of $\frac{|G_{n}|^{\frac{1}{3}}}{{\rm max}_{x \neq 1}(|C_{G_{n}}(x)|)}$ is $1 ).$

I do not know the reference for the claim about $|C_{G}(x)|^{3}$ for $x$ an involution when $G$ is non-Abelian simple. Here are some comments on related results. It is certainly true ( and a consequence of results of Brauer and Fowler) that $|G| <|C_{G}(x)|^{3}$ for some non-central element $x$ when $G$ is simple. There may be later results with which I am not familiar which show that $x$ may be chosen to be an involution. In general, Brauer and Fowler that a finite group $G$ of even order greater than $2$ has a proper subgroup $H$ with $|H|^{3} >|G|.$ I think it is a consequence of results of Burness, Liebeck and Saxl that the only non-trivial finite groups $G$ which do not have a proper subgroup $H$ with $|H|^{2} > |G|$ have order $p$ or $p^{2}$ for some prime $p$ (though this result may be older- it certainly requires CFSG).

Here is an outline: there is clearly such an $H$ if $G$ is a $p$-group of order at least $p^{3}$ for some prime $p.$ There is clearly such an $H$ ( which may be taken to be a suitable Hall subgroup) when $G$ is solvable, but not a $p$-group for any prime $p.$
Suppose then that $G$ is not solvable, and let $M$ be the terminal member of the derived series of $G.$ Suppose that $M < G.$ If $[G:M] = p$ for some prime $p,$ then we can take $H=M$ unless $|M| <p.$ But in the latter case, we can take $H$ to be a subgroup of order $p.$ If $[G:M] = p^{2}$ for some prime $p,$ then we can take $H$ to be a maximal normal subgroup of $G$ containing $M.$ Otherwise, we can choose $H$ to be a proper subgroup of $G$, containing $M$, of maximal order.

Suppose then that $G$ is perfect. The results cited above deal with the case that $G$ is non-Abelian simple, so suppose otherwise, and let $M$ be a maximal normal subgroup of $G.$ Then $G/M$ is non-Abelian simple, and there is a proper subgroup $H$, containing $M,$ of the required order.